# How to add multiplayer in Android?

Tags: java, android, networking

I'm making a Tic Tac Toe game in Android with three options:One player,               two players and multiplayer.
The first two options were easy to make but I'm having A LOT of troubles with        the last one, I have no idea what to do.
  I am a beginner java programmer and I've never worked on networking with java,   I      know some basic things like MySQL and web stuff but I dont think it has anything to do with android.

So my questions are:

1. Do I have to use a server for this type of game? how and where do I find servers for this?
2. What do I need to learn in order to have the knowledge for developing multiplayer games?
3. Is it possible to make players play with other random available players? just hit play and be ready to go.
4. Can you recommend me some good guides that could help me?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Related: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687598/how-to-make-multiplayer-game) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042089/how-to-go-about-setting-up-a-java-server-and-database-for-a-multiplayer-android).

Comment: @computerfreaker, the questions you linked seem to be talking about real-time multiplayer games. Since this is a turn-based game, I think there are simpler options to implement it. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at [Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart).

It comes with a tone of features, and, most important for you, it has a Turn Based Multiplayer option that you could maybe use in your Tic Tac Toe.

Comment: I forgot to mention something; I want to work with sockets ;)      Do I need a server for using sockets? I don't want to host from my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/)

1. Firebase can act as a server where the users are connected
2. Firebase provides Realtime Database which would help your app. for eg 
   when a player makes a move, the changes would be effected to all the other player devices in Realtime by Firebase itself, you won't have to write the code to keep them in Sync